# Convert special characters like fancy quotes

Tags: php, javascript, utf-8

I'm having issues with user inputting fancy quotes. By the time they hit the database (after being serialized by php) they are bad characters like â€.

This line fixes the problem for fancy quotes but I'm assuming that there are other characters that will also cause problems, so I'd like a more generic/overall fix for the issue.

```
var copy = $('#Copy').val().replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "'").replace(/[\u201C\u201D]/g, '"');
```

This line replaces them with standard versions. The html versions will not work.

Using the javascript function escape() does not work since it replaces spaces which will fail on validation.

The page is set to utf-8 with meta charset="utf-8"

Because of the complexities of the final data, I'd rather handle this in javascript as opposed to PHP. But if I have to handle it on the PHP side, that can work as well.

Comment: Have you tried `SET names UTF-8` as the first query after establishing the database connection?

Comment: You should probably handle it in the back-end to prevent against exploits.

Comment: What about using `utf8_encode()` in PHP and `unescape(encodeURIComponent("my utf8"));` in Javascript to encode utf8 data.

Comment: hek2mgl - Yes I've tried `SET names UTF-8` with no benefit

Comment: crush - those actually makes it worse, both individually and separately.